# How to know from which child is emitting an event in vue.js 3?

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events, vuejs3

If I have a component:

```
<product-display 
  :premium="premium" 
  :cart="cart" 
  @add-to-cart='updateCart' 
  @remove-from-cart='removeById'>
</product-display>
```

with these two methods:

```
 methods: {
        removeFromCart() {
            this.$emit('remove-from-cart', this.variants[this.selectedVariant].id)
        },
        addToCart() {
            this.$emit('add-to-cart', this.variants[this.selectedVariant].id)
        },
```

And the parent has these methods:

```
 methods: {
        updateCart (id) {
            this.cart.push(id)
        },
        removeById(id) {
            const index = this.cart.indexOf(id)
                if (index > -1) {
                    this.cart.splice(index, 1)
                }
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to remove one method from the parent and use only `updateCart(id)` knowing from which child is emitting the event?

So in the HTML you end up with:

```
 @add-to-cart='updateCart' 
 @remove-from-cart='updateCart'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in a few different ways. My preferred one is like this:

```
// Component.vue
updateCart(action) {
  this.$emit('update-cart', {
    id: this.variants[this.selectedVariant].id), action
}
```

```
//Parent.vue
@update-cart='updateCart'

methods: {
  updateCard({id, action}) {
    if (action == 'add') {
      return this.cart.push(id);
    }
    this.card = this.card.filter(x => x != id);
  }
}
```